# Unmarshaling class that extends abstract generic class

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, unmarshalling

My hierarchy of classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class GenericItem  {
    @XmlElement(name = "Id", required = true)
    private String itemId;
    ////other fields
} 

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item extends GenericItem {
   @XmlElement(name = "AreaType", required = true)
   private String areaType;
   ///other fields
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class GenericData<T extends GenericItem>{

  @XmlElement(name = "Item")
  private List<T> itemList;

  public List<T> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
  }

  public void setItemList(List<T> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
  }
  ////other fields
}


 @XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Data extends GenericData<Item> {
   ////other fields
 }
```

When I try to unmarahal XML-document that looks like

```
 <Data>
   <Item/>
   <Item/>
 </Date>
```

I have error *javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2;Unable to create an instance of GenericItem]*

```
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class, GenericData.class,Item.class, GenericItem.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        --error here--> JAXBElement<Data> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Data.class);
```

Please, I need help :(

Comment: remove abstract for class GenericItem and GenericData and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, remove the abstract key word and try for the generic classes.

```
list of java classes to be recognized by the new JAXBContext.
```

This is what documentation says for **classesToBeBound** parameters, which says it should be able to create a new object to recognize the parameters. In case of abstract class, it is not possible.

Try with a combination of `@MappedSuperclass` and `@XmlSeeAlso`. Annotate the base classes with those and make them abstract.